# How do I use an "AndAlso" in a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am looking to select all elements of type input and select, but only if their id isn't null.

I've gotten this:

```
$('input, select')
```

for the element types and this:

```
$(*[id])
```

for not null ids. I have no idea how to combine them into:

```
((isSelect || isInput) && id != null)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `((isSelect || isInput) && id != null)` equivalent to `(isSelect && id != null) || (isInput && id != null)`?

Comment: @mellamokb Looks that way. What's your point?

Comment: I was restating the condition in a way that would be easier to convert into a selector, same thing that @JamesAllardice gave in his answer.

Comment: @mellamokb Now that I understand the syntax can be used that way, yes, it's clearer. I didn't know you could do that. Very cool now that I know.

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks, btw. Looking at it that way in the future will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the attribute selector after each element selector:

```
var elems = $('input[id], select[id]');
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/jCgat/).

Also note that (in browsers that support `querySelectorAll`, at least) this should be [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/jq-attrselector-vs-filter) than using `.filter()`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select all inputs and select elements then filter them to only inputs and selects that have an id.

```
$("input,select").filter("[id]");
```